# AS3 string util to convert to x-www-form-urlencoded?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, string

Is there a library for converting strings in as3 into the application/x-www-form-urlencoded format?

Specifically, I am looking for the same functionality as the java URLEncoder http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html

Unfortunately, as3's escape and encodeURIComponent functions don't do it.  For example, lots of %20s instead of +'s.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For encoding URL parameters, both %20 and + are valid representations of the space character, and both [URLVariables.toString()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLVariables.html#toString()) and [URLUtil.objectToString()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/utils/URLUtil.html#objectToString()) emit compliant application/x-www-form-urlencoded data using the former (per [ECMA-262](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf)).  The [encodeURI()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/package.html#encodeURI()), [encodeURIComponent()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/package.html#encodeURIComponent()) and [escape()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/package.html#escape()) functions all operate similarly.  From the AS3 docs:

> [**flash.net.URLVariables.toString()**](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLVariables.html#toString())
>
> Returns a string containing all
> enumerable variables, in the MIME
> content encoding
> application/x-www-form-urlencoded.
>
> [**mx.utils.URLUtil.objectToString()**](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/utils/URLUtil.html#objectToString())
>
> You typically use this method to convert
> an ActionScript object to a String
> that you then append to the end of a
> URL. By default, invalid URL
> characters are URL-encoded (converted
> to the %XX format).
>
> [**encodeURIComponent()**](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/package.html#encodeURIComponent())
>
> Encodes a string into a valid URI component.
> Converts a substring of a URI into a
> string in which all characters are
> encoded as UTF-8 escape sequences
> unless a character belongs to a very
> small group of basic characters.
>
> [**escape()**](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/package.html#escape())
>
> Converts the parameter to a
> string and encodes it in a URL-encoded
> format, where most nonalphanumeric
> characters are replaced with %
> hexadecimal sequences.

Here's an example showing the usage and output of all four approaches:

```
import mx.utils.URLUtil;

private function test():void
{
    var url:String = "http://www.google.com/search?";
    var s:String = "here is my search query";
                    
    var variables:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
    variables.q = s;
    
    var o:Object = new Object();
    o.q = s;
                               
    trace(url + "q=" + encodeURIComponent(s));
    trace(url + variables.toString());
    trace(url + "q=" + escape(s));
    trace(url + URLUtil.objectToString(o));
}
```

All four emit the same result (just as JavaScript's own encodeURIComponent() does):

```
// http://www.google.com/search?q=here%20is%20my%20search%20query
```

I agree the plus signs are easier on the eyes, though!  To swap them out manually:

```
trace(url + "q=" + escape(s).split("%20").join("+"));
```

But if there's an ActionScript class or top-level function that uses plus signs instead of hex sequences for spaces, I'm not aware of it.

Comment: String "c++ is fun" when encoded by escape(s).split("%20").join("+") is "c+++is+fun", which is impossible to decode to the original.  Pluses need to be swapped for %2B's first, right?

Comment: Right, that's a good point.  (Personally I don't like the idea of swapping out the plus signs, anyway.)

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add that **escape** and **encodeURIComponent** will only give the same result if the string in **not** mutlibyte. In the case of a multibyte string like ñ (in Spanish) escape() will not encode the value correcltly. using encodeURIComponent  and decodeURIComponent will. I found out the hardway trying to use escape() on multibyte string using new navigateToURL(new URLRequest( which will fail silently when using the mailto URL.